# Não consigo fazer o ValidationError aparecer na página html

Tags: python-3.x, django

Criei um formulário e caso o CPF já exista no banco de dados, é necessário imprimir isso na tela para o usuário, mas minhas tentativas têm sido frustradas. Alguém poderia me ajudar a entender onde estou errando?

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from cpf_field.models import CPFField

# Create your models here.
class Cadastro_alunos(models.Model):
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    user_cpf = CPFField('cpf', unique=True)
    user_email = models.EmailField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    user_password = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    user_genre = models.IntegerField()
```

**cadastro.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Matrícula</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
 <div class="col-8 m-auto pt-2 pb-2 text-center">
        <h1>Matricule-se</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-8 m-auto pt-3 pb-2 text-center">
        <a href="/" class="btn btn-info">Voltar</a>
    </div>

    <div class="col-8 m-auto pt-4 pb-2 text-center">
        <form name="form" id="form" action="/create/" method="post">
            {%csrf_token%}

    <!--        {{form.as_p}}-->
            <div class="form-group mt-4">Nome Completo: {{form.user_name}}</div>
            <div class="form-group mt-4">CPF: {{form.user_cpf}}</div>
            <div class="form-group mt-4">Email: {{form.user_email}}</div>
            <div class="form-group mt-4">Senha: {{form.user_password}}</div>
            <div class="form-group mt-4">Sexo: {{form.user_genre}}</div>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Matricular">

        </form>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

**forms.py**

```
    from django.forms import ModelForm
    from cadastro.models import Cadastro_alunos
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
    from django import forms
    from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
    
    # Create the form class.
    class CadastroForm(ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Cadastro_alunos
            fields = ['user_name',
                      'user_cpf',
                      'user_email',
                      'user_password',
                      'user_genre',]
    
        def clean_cpf(self, *args, **kwargs):
            x = Cadastro_alunos.user_cpf
            cpf = self.cleaned_data['user_cpf']
            if User.objects.filter(x=cpf).exists():
                raise ValidationError(f'O CPF {cpf}já está cadastrado.')
            return cpf
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from cadastro.forms import CadastroForm

def cadastro_usuario(request):
    data = {}
    data['form'] = CadastroForm()
    return render(request, 'cadastro.html', data)
def create(request):

    form = CadastroForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        user_name = form.cleaned_data['user_name']
        user_cpf = form.cleaned_data['user_cpf']
        user_password = form.cleaned_data['user_password']
        user_genre = form.cleaned_data['user_genre']
        user_email = form.cleaned_data['user_email']
        return redirect('https://icegetec.com.br/')
     else:
         form = CadastroForm
         context = {
           'form': form
       }
         return render(request, 'cadastro.html', context)
         # return redirect('cadastro')
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 1):

O erro está no seu `views.py` e no `cadastro.html`

Você possui uma rota com 3 possibilidades.

1. O usuário acessa a rota (renderizar o form), método HTML --> GET
2. O usuário estando na rota faz um submit, método HTML --> POST
3. O usuário estando na rota faz um submit, e ocorre um erro de validação, método html --> POST (mas neste caso deve renderizar o form, com os dados preenchidos e apenas com o erro de validação em destaque.

Desta forma, podemos implementar este fluxo em nosso `views.py`, da seguinte forma:

```
# Destacando apenas as partes relevantes
def cadastro_usuario(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # fluxo descrito em 2 e 3 <--
        return create(request)
    else:
        # fluxo descrito em 1 <--
        return new(request)

def new(request):
    # 1
    return render(request, 'cadastro.html', {'form': CadastroForm()})

def create(request):
    form = CadastroForm(request.POST)
    if not form.is_valid():
       # fluxo descrito em 3 <--
       return render(request, 'cadastro.html', {'form': form})
    # fluxo descrito em 2 <--
    obj = form.save()
    return redirect('https://icegetec.com.br/')
```

Além dessas mudanças, será  necessário adicionar ao seu html as tags necessárias para o html renderizar os erros.
Vou mostrar um exemplo de como deveria ser o seu html:

```
<div class="col-8 m-auto pt-4 pb-2 text-center">
    <form name="form" id="form" action="/create/" method="post">
        {%csrf_token%}
        <div class="form-group mt-4">Nome Completo: {{form.user_name}} {{form.user_name.errors}}</div>
        <div class="form-group mt-4">CPF: {{form.user_cpf}}{{form.user_cpf.errors}}</div>
        <div class="form-group mt-4">Email: {{form.user_email}}{{form.user_email.errors}}</div>
        <div class="form-group mt-4">Senha: {{form.user_password}}{{form.user_password.errors}}</div>
        <div class="form-group mt-4">Sexo: {{form.user_genre}}{{form.user_genre.errors}}</div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Matricular">
    </form>
</div>
```

A diferença aqui é que estou adicionando os widgets contendo as mensagens de erro de cada atributo.

Uma sugestão de implementação é que você faça forms html pensando na usabilidade e acessibilidade. Então o que eu sugiro é a utilização da seguinte boa prática:

```
<form action="." method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    
    <div class="form-group mt-4">
        <label for="{{ form.user_name.id_for_label }}">{{ form.user_name.label }}:</label>
        {{form.user_name}} {{form.user_name.errors}}
    </div>
<!-- Adicionar os outros atributos -->
<!-- ... -->
</form>
```

A diferença é que desta forma estamos renderizando um form em que o usuário é capaz de interagir com os rótulos (`labels`) para fazer o preenchimento dos campos de entrada de dados.
Desta forma também pegamos o rótulo através do atributo declarado no model, isso facilita a vida quando usamos internacionalização. Já que os valores do rótulos não são uma constante e podem ser modificadas em tempo de execução se utilizando uma lib tipo o `django.utils.translations` utilizando o método `ugettext` que é capaz de fazer a internacionalização do nome do atributo no momento da renderização do html.

Para mais informações consulte a documentação de [`formulários do Django e renderização de erros de validação`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/forms/)